# App load screen in Android

Tags: android

On iOS you create a load screen for when the app loads, is there a similar thing in Android. When my app loads, I get a black screen until it opens.

Comment: Are you asking how to create a page to display while your resources are loading, or how to manipulate how your first screen appears on the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm in no way a iOS expert, but if you're referring to a splash screen, you can do the following:

Create an Activity that it's intent-filter category is set as LAUNCHER in the manifest... say you call it Splash:

```
<activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Splash" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then in the new Activity `onCreate` execute a `postDelay`  to start a new Intent:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(Splash.this, MyMainActivity.class);
            Splash.this.startActivity(intent);
            Splash.this.finish();
        }
    }, 3000); // splash will show for 3 seconds
```

Comment: this is not the answer to the question, its an alternative, http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/

Answer (score 0):

Just make your main (startup) screen an ImageView (or whatever you want your splash screen to have) and then call `StartActivity()` to start your *real* main screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could display an Activity with a custom View that displays on animated image (using the LayoutInflater to inflate, and an Animation to animate it). Thats how I did it.